# A function that is neither O(gi(n)) nor Ω(gi(n))

Tags: asymptotics

I have two functions

$$g_1(n) = 1$$

$$g_2(n) = 10^{10^n}$$

I have to find one function that is neither $O(g_i(n))$ nor $Ω(g_i(n))$ ($i=1,2$). I already have :
$$f(n) = 2 \sin (n)$$
That should be enough for $g_1(n)$, but I don't know how to come up with a function (or modify $f(n)$) so that it handles $g_2(n)$. I think that I should find a function that alternates near the $y$-axis.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I think $f(n) = 2\sin(n) = \mathcal{O}(g_1(n)) = \mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: @np-hard I don't think it is. The limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $1/(2sin(n))$ is not infinity.

Comment: By definition, $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g_1(n))$ since $|f(n)| \leq 2 \cdot |g_1(n)|$ for $\forall n > 0$.

Comment: @np-hard So how do you propose we solve this problem?

Comment: For $g_1(n) = 1$, you can define $f(n) = \begin{cases} n & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\ 0 & \text{if } n \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$

Comment: For $g_1$, try $f_1(n)=n^{(-1)^n}$. For $g_2$, try $f_2(n)=f_1(n)g_2(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that
$$f(n)= 10^{(-11)^n}$$ works, and it has the advantage of being always positive.

EXPLANATION: In general, for positive functions $f,g$, $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ is equivalent on saying that $$f(n) \le C g(n)$$
i.e. $f(n)/g(n)$ is bounded. Similarly, $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$ means that $g(n)/f(n)$ is bounded.

1. $f (n) \in O(1)$ means that $f(n)$ is bounded
2. $f (n) \in O(10^{10^n})$ means that $f(n)/10^{10^n}$ is bounded
3. $f (n) \in \Omega(1)$ means that $1/f(n)$ is bounded
4. $f (n) \in \Omega(10^{10^n})$ means that $10^{10^n}/f(n)$ is bounded

Now, note that 1 implies 2 , and 4 implies 3. So, you want to find a function $f$ not satisfying 2 and 3.

Take a function such that even indices do not satisfy 2 and odd indices do not satisfy 3, and you are done.

Comment: Why does 1 imply 2 and 4 imply 3?

Comment: Also, how can point 3 be violated? If you take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $1/10^{-11^n}$ you get 0

Comment: It's not $10^{-11^n}$. It's $10^{(-11)^n}$, which is different. For even indices this is a very large number, while for odd indices it's a small number very close to $0$.